# Is it recommended you remove all non-essential links, navigation items, promo buckets etc when users engage in a elaborate tool/flow on your site?

Tags: ux-field

I know this is the case for registration where you dont want the user to bail. A good example would be creating a map on Google Maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Designing for Emotion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1937557006) does into a bit of detail on this (specifically about registration as well); many good sites will cut back "frills" when an important task is at hand.

For instance [Carbonnade](http://carbonmade.com/) lays on the fluff and fancy pretty heavily on their opening page; it's meant to entice and be fun. Once you log in much of the extras disappear, and once you're reading someone's portfolio the "fun" bits go away; they would be distracting and even unprofessional.

In addition these extra links and such add to [Cognitive Load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_load), which I discuss in detail [in this related answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14836/why-do-some-apps-feel-heavy-or-light/14853#14853). **The more complex your task is the more important cognitive load is**; distracting users with extra elements can only have a harmful effect.

Lots of research has been done on [distractions and their impact on performance](http://www.igi-global.com/article/journal-organizational-end-user-computing/37217), though often in the context of real-world distractions, but the general result is pretty obvious; **distractions harm task performance**, especially with complex tasks.

That said, removing navigation isn't always the best idea, a user may want basic navigation to exit the task. Definitely remove ads, read more links, unnecessary junk like that.

Comment: Phenomenal answer; thanks so much for sharing these resources!